# How include more than 1 indicator with Highstock

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

I have two questions:

- 1) I would like to show my candle chart with the volume, and more indicators below (rsi, macd, adx ...), like the following example but without using the blacklabel plugin

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jLpbL1db/)

```
(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }


        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            indicators: [{
                id: "AAPL",
                type: "rsi"
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                id: "AAPL",
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Is this possible with highstock or even combined with highchart?

I honestly do not need to calculate the indicators with any plugin, I did it on my own, I just need to represent them.

- 2) Is it possible to pass the values to the highstock indicators in some way, or not?

Comment: check https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/technical-indicator-series and demo http://jsfiddle.net/tcem9y4k/

Comment: Have you considered adding a regular series (line, column etc.) with the values you calculated on your own? Documentation says that indicators are just aregular series with automatically computed values: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/technical-indicator-series

Comment: I have managed to put more than one indicator, but I have not gotten it that you comment on passing the values that I have calculated for the indicator in question, do you have any functional example?